# How to automatically populate cursor in textarea?

Tags: javascript

I want javascript that will automatically populate the blinking cursor in a text box on a new page, instead of having people click on the text box to type their response. I have been searching multiple forums but cannot find an answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Find the element in the DOM and call the focus method.
Something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
if(x.length > 0)
    x[0].focus();
```

Find working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pwse652d/

This is very simple and stupid implementation just to explain how it could be done. You might like to find element by using class selector and if using JQuery or something of like, little different then.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript to do that, although you can use it if you *really* want.

Just add the `autofocus` attribute to the `textarea`.

```
<textarea name="message" autofocus></textarea>
```

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript.

```
document.querySelector('textarea[name="message"]').focus();
```

Comment: autofocus attribute works on HTML5 compatible browsers only. So may be worth mentioning.

Comment: Support is available in [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=autofocus) and IE10+, but yes, JavaScript would be required for older browsers.